# Describe all activities in AndroidManifest just once

Tags: android, android-manifest

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have registered a few activities that are described with the same attributes. Just `name`s are different.

Is it possible to define some attributes group and use this defined group to describe all of those activities ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly that is not possible.

The AndroidManifest.xml is parsed by different applications (like the launcher) and thus activities can't be grouped as they are the official entry points to your application.